# Node does not send response after child process exits

Tags: node.js, express, child-process

I have the following route:

```
app.get('/downloadSentinel', function (req,res){
var promObj = {};
var data = req.query.data;
var Name = req.query.name;
namesArray = [];
for(var i =0;i<Name.length;i++){
    namesArray.push(Name[i]);
}
promObj['Name'] = namesArray;
console.log(promObj.Name);
requestarray = [];
for (i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
    requestarray.push(data[i]);
    promObj['requestURLS'] = requestarray;
}

createResultFolder(promObj)
   .then(downloadSentinel)
.then(resp => {
    console.log("THEN:", resp);
    res.send(resp);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("CATCH:", err)
   res.send(err);

})

});
```

The function downloadSentinel calls a Node child process and looks like this:

```
function downloadSentinel(promObj){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
        var sys = require('util'),
            exec = require('child_process').exec,
            child;

        var urls = parseArrayForBash(promObj.requestURLS);
        var names = parseArrayForBash(promObj.Name);

            console.log("executing:", './downloadProducts.sh ' + urls + ' ' + names);
            child = exec('bash downloadProducts.sh '+ urls + ' ' + names, [{stdio:'inherit'}]);

            child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
            child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

            child.on("error", function (error) {
                console.log("child error:", error);
                reject(promObj)
            })

            child.on('data', function (data) {
                console.log(data.toString());

            });

            child.on('exit', function (exit) {
                console.log("child exit:", exit);
                resolve(promObj);
            })
        }
    })
 }
```

The output of downloadSentinel is :

```
child exit: 0
THEN: { Name:
[ 'S2A_MSIL1C_20180315T041541_N0206_R090_T46QEH_20180315T075531',
 'S2A_MSIL1C_20180315T041541_N0206_R090_T46QEK_20180315T075531' ],
requestURLS:
[ 'bb5f4946-ce18-4b50-97ba-7ac9a94d9f1e',
 'ec15c5d4-0cc6-44d4-a11f-6c2e9055f2e4' ] }
```

So I think that everything works as expected. But after the child process has exited with code 0, the response `res.send(resp);` is not sent to the client and I never get the sucess message.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: Sorry for the large amount of code, but I don't know what I made wrong so I provided everything.

**EDIT**
For the client part I am using this jQuery Ajax Request:

```
function downloadSentinelData(ID,Name){
var url = encodeURI('/downloadSentinel?');
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:  url,
    timeout:5000,
    dataType:'json',
    data: {
        data: ID,
        name: Name
    },
    success: function(data,status){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        alert('Products downloaded. Processing now.');
    },
    error: function (errorMessage) {
    }
});
}
```

Could there be a mistake?

Comment: I've tested your code out as much as I can.. it works for me using curl.. it's a strange one. If you're getting to the console.log line 'THEN', there isn't much that can go wrong after that. Could this be an issue on the client side? Have you tested using curl, postman etc.?

Comment: Yes, it has to do something with the Ajax request but I don't what could be wrong there.

Comment: @TerryLennox I posted it in the Edit

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that! You're not running into any CORS issue are you? Is the client code served from the same domain and port as the data from the node.js server? Do you see any errors in the dev. console in Chrome/Firefox?

Comment: I found my mistake, I tried execSync() before and therefore I changed my Ajax request to async='false' and set the timeout. I forgot to take the timeout out. I was so focused on the server side, sorry. Thanks for your time, you helped me a lot.

Comment: Nice one! Glad to hear it !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express.js, you should do res.end() after the res.send